# Jquery autocomplete :: clear cache

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using Jquery autocomplet for two fields, Country and state.
I want the states list according to country value and I am getting this too.

My problem is that state auto complete also show the result of previous country seach. I know this is because jquery cache the result.

Some one please guide me how to solve this

My code is below

```
$('#khk_adressen_LieferLand').autocomplete("/countries/auto_complete_for_countries_list",{
flushCache: function() {
     return this.trigger("flushCache");
  }
});


$('#khk_adressen_LieferPLZ').autocomplete("/postals/auto_complete_for_postals_list", {
               flushCache: function() {
     return this.trigger("flushCache");
  },
  extraParams: {
      country_name: function() { return $("#khk_adressen_LieferLand").val(); }
  }

});
```

Thansk in advance

Comment: Can you please post your code .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#country_id").result(function()
{
    $("#state_id").flushCache();
});
```

It will clear the cache after they select the country.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this way. you can set everythig....try.........

```
 $("#setcommonelement_ElementName").autocomplete(data, {
        minChars: 0,
        width: 262,
        matchContains: "word",
        scrollHeight: 220,    
        cacheLength: 0

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> $("#element").unautocomplete();

$("#element").autocomplete(newData);